# Read table by delimiter then by fixed width in R

Tags: r, io, data-manipulation

I have a tab-delimited file like this:

```
RS1->2001 HAPLO1 AAACAAGGAGGAGAAGGAAA ...
RS1->2001 HAPLO2 CAACAAAGAGGAGAAGGAAA ...
RS1->2002 HAPLO1 AAAAAAGGAGGAAAAGGAAA ...
RS1->20020 HAPLO2 CAACAAGGAGGAAGCAGAGC ...
RS1->20021 HAPLO2 CAACAAGGAGGAAGCAGAGC ...
```

In R we can easily read in these three columns, my problem is that I need separate the 3rd column character by character. The end result should be something like this:

```
RS1->2001 HAPLO1 A A A C  ...
RS1->2001 HAPLO2 C A A C  ...
RS1->2002 HAPLO1 A A A A  ...
RS1->20020 HAPLO2 C A A C  ...
RS1->20021 HAPLO2 C A A C  ...
```

I can first read the 3 columns in, then split each entry of the 3rd column into characters, but this is annoying, I would very much prefer to get it right from the start.

If the first two columns does not existe, I can achieve the goal with

```
read.fwf('test.csv', widths=rep(1, 300))
```

I am thinking whether I can read in the first 2 columns in by using the tab delimiter and then read the 3rd column by fixed width.

Comment: `strsplit` should work fine with `split = ""`.

Comment: You can read your file as usual (say `SplitMe <- read.csv("test.csv")`). Then, presuming your third column is called "V3", you can use `read.fwf(file=textConnection(SplitMe$V3), widths = rep(1, 20))` to split it. Combining the two: `cbind(SplitMe[-3], read.fwf(file=textConnection(SplitMe$V3), widths = rep(1, 20))` should do it with this example. Replace the numbers as needed for your actual data.

Comment: @AnandaMahto That's very nice. Why don't you post it as an answer? I would be very glad to accept it.

Comment: @CravingSpirit, done. I didn't post it as an answer originally because it looked like you had already sort of found an answer with `read.fwf` -- but I'm guessing you were missing the `textConnection` part. For some reason, while `read.table` and so on got a `text` argument, `read.fwf` is still stuck with a `file` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main options that come to mind are `strsplit` (as mentioned in the comments and in @Ricardo's answer) and `read.fwf`. `read.fwf` won't work directly with your data, but it can work on a column of data that has already been read in if you use the `textConnection()` function.

Here's a basic example:

```
## Create a tab-separated file named "test.txt" in your working directory
cat("2001\tHAPLO1\tAAACAAGGAGGAGAAGGAAA\n",
    "2001\tHAPLO2\tCAACAAAGAGGAGAAGGAAA\n",
    "2002\tHAPLO1\tAAAAAAGGAGGAAAAGGAAA\n",
    "20020\tHAPLO2\tCAACAAGGAGGAAGCAGAGC\n",
    "20021\tHAPLO2\tCAACAAGGAGGAAGCAGAGC\n", 
    file = "test.txt")

## Read it in with `read.delim`
mydata <- read.delim("test.txt", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Use `read.fwf` on the third column
## Replace "widths" with whatever the maximum width is for that column
## If max width is not known, you can use something like
##    `widths = rep(1, max(nchar(mydata$V3)))`
cbind(mydata[-3], 
      read.fwf(file = textConnection(mydata$V3), widths = rep(1, 20)))
#      V1     V2 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
# 1  2001 HAPLO1  A  A  A  C  A  A  G  G  A   G   G   A   G   A   A   G   G   A   A   A
# 2  2001 HAPLO2  C  A  A  C  A  A  A  G  A   G   G   A   G   A   A   G   G   A   A   A
# 3  2002 HAPLO1  A  A  A  A  A  A  G  G  A   G   G   A   A   A   A   G   G   A   A   A
# 4 20020 HAPLO2  C  A  A  C  A  A  G  G  A   G   G   A   A   G   C   A   G   A   G   C
# 5 20021 HAPLO2  C  A  A  C  A  A  G  G  A   G   G   A   A   G   C   A   G   A   G   C
```

Note: If you did not use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, you would have to change your `file` argument to:

```
file = textConnection(as.character(mydata$V3))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Ananda alludes to in the comments, `strsplit` if asked to split on `""` will split every letter.

```
fContents <- read.csv("/path/to/file.csv")

 # This will chop it up for you.
 strsplit(fContents[, 3], "")
```

In order to combine it, use cbind

```
cbind(fContents[, -3],
       do.call(rbind, strsplit(fContents[, 3], ""))
      )

# or if you'd like to keep the columns ordered (and there are more than 3):
cbind(fContents[, 1:2], 
      do.call(rbind, strsplit(fContents[, 3], "")),
      fContents[, 4:ncol(fContents)]
)
```

Comment: This will, of course, create a `list` for the third column. Perhaps `cbind(fileContents, do.call(rbind, strsplit(fileContents[, 3], "")))` might be more "typical user expectation" (but would also depend on the data being rectangular in order to work).

Comment: @AnandaMahto, it's really just a basic `cbind` statement.  The included `if` statement is just a succinct way of writing "if your data has more than 3 columns..."

Comment: Ahh. I see. You were assuming that there might be more than 3 columns. But I think to get it to work with the `if`, you'd have to do something like `cbind(fContents[, 1:2],
      if (ncol(fContents) == 3L) {
        do.call(rbind, strsplit(fContents[, 3], ""))
      } else if (ncol(fContents) > 3) {
        cbind(do.call(rbind, strsplit(fContents[, 3], "")),
              fContents[, 4:ncol(fContents)])
      })`. Anyway, +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
file_read = csv.reader(open('/path/to/file.csv','r'),delimiter='\t')
file_write = csv.writer(open('/path/to/newfile.csv','w'),delimiter='\t')
for i in file_read:
    first=i[0]
    second=i[1]
    third = i[3]
    splitchar = [k for k in third]
    outputdata = [first,second,splitchar]
    file_write.writerow(outputdata)
```