# Error when reading in a .txt file and splitting it into columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to read in a .txt file into R, and have done so numerous times.
At the moment however, I am not getting the desired output.

I have a .txt file which contains data X that I want, and other data that I do not, which is in front and after this data X.

Here is a printscreen of the .txt file

[image]

I am able to read in the txt file as followed:

```
read.delim("C:/Users/toxicologie/Cobalt/WB1", header=TRUE,skip=88, nrows=266)
```

This gives me a dataframe with 266 obs of 1 variable.
[image]

But I want these 266 observations in 4 columns (ID, Species, Endpoint, BLM NOEC).

So I tried the following script:

```
read.delim("C:/Users/toxicologie/Cobalt/WB1", header=TRUE,skip=88, nrows=266, sep = " ")
```

But then I get the error

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : more columns than column names
```

Using sep = "\t" also gives the same error.

And I am not sure how I can fix this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `read.fwf` and specify the widths of each column. Start reading at the *Aelososoma sp.* row and add the column names afterwards with

something like:

```
df <-  read.fwf("C:/Users/toxicologie/Cobalt/WB1", header=TRUE,skip=88, n=266,widths=c(2,35,15,15))

colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Species", "Endpoint", "BLM NOEC")
```

Provide the txt file for a more complete answer.

Comment: I would like to add the txt file, but don't know how to. Could you tell me? Thank you

Comment: Upload it to dropbox and provide the public link?

Comment: @JT85, not a very good idea for best practices on SO, since the OP may delete the file at some point rendering the utility of the answer much lower in the long run. Instead, provide code to create a sample file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto.This is difficult. A dput could not recreate her file because of the noise lines at the top. I think the only possibility in this case is or provide the file itself or copy paste a part of it.

Comment: I changed the 'widths' specification, and now it works like a charm! Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @JT85, only a few lines are really needed to be able to demonstrate the problem, for which you can easily use `cat` to write a set of strings to a test file for a demo that can be read in. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17984304/1270695).

Comment: @JT85, FYI, here's a small "[proof of concept](http://ideone.com/qPE7rc)". Enjoy! :)